Setup Custom Functions Postgres for Django Testdatabase
i have a test database(PostGres) that can be rebuild if wanted. When i rebuild the database the custom function i have wrote for it are gone. My first thought are somthing like checking with the pg_proc if the current function exists like this:
      SELECT 1
        FROM pg_proc
        WHERE proname = 'test_function'

if not i would use the CREATE FUNCTION test_function() to create the function on the database. Is this a proper way, or is there a better solution in the django rest frame with postgres for this problem?
Deskresearch in the internet, documentation

Add these in a migration, so that these will be created when migrating the test database.

That a function with this name exists, doesn't mean that all functions with this name exists. Check overloading: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-overload.html
